# Can any method replace httpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm actually developing an android application , the problem is the application is compatible only with the versions 2.2 and 2.3

After researches, I found that the function HttpUrlConnection can't be used in the android devices with recent versions than 2.3 which make my application not compatible with the versions 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 .. 4.4

Is there another function to use and replace HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: If you want help, you have to describe the problems you're observing. Provide a stacktrace of what is not working with > 2.3. BTW HttpURLConnection is not a function, it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpURLConnection` works on all versions of Android, though [it is only recommended for Android 2.3 and above](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) due to some bugs on older devices. For older devices, either consider [OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (Android 2.2+) or HttpClient.

Comment: so can you help me please , what's the thing that make my application not compatible with the recent versions of android
"  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />  "

Comment: @user3442307: I have no idea. Perhaps you might consider asking a new StackOverflow question, where you provide a complete description of your problem. In particular, you might explain there what specific symptoms you are seeing that indicate that your application is "not compatible with the recent versions of android".